# Query to get the latest build notes which is not null and doesnt match a string

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-performance

I am trying to get the build_notes from a database table "build_wiki_notes_meta" with following conditions,I am using the below query which doesn't give my any output,can anyone provide guidance on how to fix this?what is wrong?is there a better query(faster)?

1.MAX `date_created`

2.MATCHES a given `software_product_id`

3.build_notes is NOT `null`

4.build_notes doesn't match `Currently no notes for this build`

QUERY:

```
select
    meta_name,
    build_notes
from
(
    select meta_name, MAX(date_created) AS date_created, build_notes
    from build_wiki_notes_meta
    where software_product_id = 105
    order by date_created desc
) as tmp 
where (tmp.build_notes is NOT null) AND
      (tmp.build_notes NOT LIKE '%Currently no notes for this build%')
```

Database table:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your current query has several problems, and I also could not think of a nice way to phrase your query other than what is given below.  You want to target a certain group of records based on a number of conditions.  In addition to those conditions, you want the record(s) having the latest date of creation.  Note that there may be a tie between two or more records for having the latest date.  The query below just uses a subquery in the `WHERE` clause to check for the latest date.

```
SELECT
    meta_name,
    build_notes
FROM build_wiki_notes_meta
WHERE
    software_product_id = 105 AND
    build_notes IS NOT NULL   AND
    build_notes NOT LIKE '%Currently no notes for this build%' AND
    date_created = (SELECT MAX(date_created) FROM build_wiki_notes_meta
                    WHERE software_product_id = 105 AND
                          build_notes IS NOT NULL   AND
                          build_notes NOT LIKE '%Currently no notes for this build%')
```

If you are certain that there will only ever be one latest record and/or you don't mind just always getting back a single record, then we can simplify this to the following:

```
SELECT
    meta_name,
    build_notes
FROM build_wiki_notes_meta
WHERE
    software_product_id = 105 AND
    build_notes IS NOT NULL   AND
    build_notes NOT LIKE '%Currently no notes for this build%'
ORDER BY date_created DESC
LIMIT 1
```